# Finding Uppercase Chars with Pattern and Matcher in Java

Tags: java, regex

I know it is really dummy question; but I'm new to use regex in Java. My code is like that.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher ("AsdGqw");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

I want uppercase chars("AG" for my code); however it prints only 'A'. When I debug, I see my matcher's lastmatch which is also 'A', and I don't know why. My regex works fine in regex tester.

I also wonder which one has better performance for finding uppercase chars. Regex or loop ?

Sorry for my dummy question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of getting your output i.e. ONLY upper case letters from given input **without any loops**:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Z]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher ("AsdGqw");
System.out.println("=> " + m.replaceAll("")); //=> AG
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make the changes as follows:

**If condition** only returns the first one, you need to use *while contidion* to return them all.

From

```
if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```

to

```
    while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Which one is better do you think loop or regex ?